# how to know list that permission used in android?

Tags: java, android, permissions

First of all, I'm not good at English. Sorry.

I want to know the list of all ***permissions not-used (but added in Manifest file)*** in Android.

More importantly, **programmatically**, not using IDE (*e.g. Analyze -> Inspect Code in Android Studio*)

What can I do?

Comment: Do you mean you want to add permission programmatically?

Comment: @Ali No. I want to know the list of not used permissions.
But, added in manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions for Android are usually added via manifest file. 
The permission added can be for the whole application . or it can be applied at the activity level as well . 
I have provided an example of how it can done .

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

This will ensure that the permissions are provided at application level.
wherein if you'd want to do it at activity level , you can enable it in the activity through code .

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will inturn call the settings page , with which you will be able to enable the app settings that is required for the application .

> **Description**

```
 Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
```

*Opens Details setting page for App. From here user have to manually assign desired permission.*

```
 Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
```

*Optional. If set then opens Settings Screen(Activity) as new activity. Otherwise, it will be opened in currently running activity.*

```
Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null)
```

*Prepares or creates URI, whereas, getPackageName() - returns name of your application package.*

```
intent.setData(uri)
```

**Don't forget to set this. Otherwise, you will get android.content.ActivityNotFoundException. Because you have set your intent as Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS and android expects some name to search.**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Haresh Raman.
But, it's not answer the I want. :(

Comment: If you have an application already as a package running on an android device , you would be able to view the permissions that are necessary for the application in the app settings > Permissions , say Phone , and storage are enabled , this would mean that : <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> are provided to the application

Comment: Thank you for reply, again.
I want to analyze from the decompiled source of apk file.
So, I have to working on source code programmatical, not function of IDE or device.
Thank you for your kind.